# How can I export unique documents based on two field values?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to export data from a collection. However, I would like to filter it so there are no two documents exported where two specified fields have the same value.

For example, see this data. I am filtering based on `field1` and `field2`:

```
1: {field1: "hello", field2: "bye", field3: "good day"}, 
2: {field1: "hello", field2: "bye", field3: "bad day"},
3: {field1: "bye", field2: "bye", field3: "good day"},
4: {field1: "hello", field2: "hello", field3: "good day"}
```

I would like it so that when this collection is exported with a filter only 1, 3 and 4 are outputted.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below query in export command :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        field1: "$field1",
        field2: "$field2"
      },
      "field3": {
        "$first": "$field3"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      field1: "$_id.field1",
      field2: "$_id.field2",
      field3: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Link to Mongo playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/jZPvOjJ9EDj